# NHibernate should always write NULL instead of empty string

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I use NHibernate 3 with Microsoft SQL Server Database (2005 and higher).
Now, I am searching a way to tell NHibernate to write always NULL to the database instead of empty strings.
What would be the best way to do this? - Or is there perhaps a switch in NHibernate to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592556/how-to-have-nhibernate-persist-a-string-empty-property-value-as-null and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187841/mapping-empty-strings-to-null-in-nhibernate

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your links. I have a question: I have seen, that they work with Fluent. I work with hbm-mappings. Will this also work with hbm-mappings?

Comment: You can use custom IUserType with hbm-mappings too. Example `<property name="Property1" column="`Property1`" type="NameSpace1.MyCustomUserType, MyAssembly" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a PreInsertEventListener and override the function to do the necessary conversion of an empty string to a NULL value.

The way to go about this would be:

```
 public class NhibernateEventListeners :  IPreInsertEventListener
    {
         public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent nHibernateEvent)
        {
            var entityBeingInserted = nHibernateEvent.Entity;
            if (entityBeingInserted == null)
                return false;
             if (property.PropertyType==typeof(string))
                 {
                    //use reflection to set the property value to null   
                 }
            return false;
        }
   }
```

and while setting up the sessionfactory make sure you add the following to your configuration

```
_config.ExposeConfiguration(
                        config => config.SetListener(ListenerType.PreInsert, new NhibernateEventListeners()));
```

Hope this is what you are looking for and helps you.